# Tension of a string in vertical circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

While finding the minimum velocity at the top-most point of the loop in vertical circular motion, why do we take the tension as zero?

Comment: The tension at the top is zero only in a special case. I suspect that you have misunderstood your book.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! Just to be clear, are you asking why the tension at the topmost point of the circle is zero, intuitively? Or are you referring to some steps in the derivation? In the latter case, it would be helpful to add it to your question. If you want, you can always add information by [edit]ing your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A string can not hold a compressive stress. So, zero is the minimum possible tension at the top, for a circular motion. But it can also be any positive value.

Comment: At higher speeds, the tension acts with gravity to produce the downward centripetal acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

At the uppermost point, centripetal force can be given by $$T+mg=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$ Though $T$ varies with the time, $mg$ doesn't. So $mg$ can produce the centripetal force alone, by itself. But you are finding the *minimum velocity*. For that you can easily see $T$ should be zero.(because $T\geq 0$)